# I have two text and I want them to appear on each other in css

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend, web-frontend

I have two text and I want them to appear on each other. I've made an animation which will let them appear on different time.
CODE OF ANIMATION

```
 @keyframes t1 {
   0% {opacity: 1;}
   30%{ opacity: 1;}
   40%{opacity: 0;}
   90%{ opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1; }
}
 
@keyframes t2 {
   0% {opacity: 0;   }
   40%{opacity: 0;}
   50%{opacity: 1;}
   80%{opacity: 1;}
   90%{opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 0; }
}
```

[this is my first text and I want my second text to appear when first one dissappears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IxRi.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use position absolute for both elements and place it relative to parent element.

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
}
p{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#first{
  animation: t1 linear 3s infinite;
}
#second{
  animation: t2 linear 3s infinite;
}
@keyframes t1 {
   0% {opacity: 1;}
   30%{ opacity: 1;}
   40%{opacity: 0;}
   90%{ opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 1; }
}
 
@keyframes t2 {
   0% {opacity: 0;   }
   40%{opacity: 0;}
   50%{opacity: 1;}
   80%{opacity: 1;}
   90%{opacity: 0;}
   100% {opacity: 0; }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <p id="first">Hello</p>
  <p id="second">Bonjour</p>
</div>
```